# Variables not incrementing within a batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

So I am trying to create a file that will read a text file called saves. In saves I want it to check up to 5 time for 1:, 2:, 3: ,4:, and 5:. The issue is that when I run this `for` loop to check the file 5 times it always outputs the same thing and no matter what will say there are no saves. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET test=0
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO (
FINDSTR %%i: Saves.txt >NUL && SET /a %test%+1
ECHO %test%
)
IF %test% EQU 0 ECHO There are no saves. & GOTO :end
IF %test% GTR 0 ECHO There are saves. 
:END
PAUSE
```

Comment: You are not using the `SET` command correctly. `set /a test+=1` and then you need to use delayed expansion to display the value correctly. `echo !test!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `SET` command correctly and you need to use delayed expansion to display the variable correctly when inside a parenthesized code block.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET test=0
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO (
    FINDSTR /B %%i: Saves.txt >NUL && SET /a test+=1
    ECHO !test!
)
IF %test% EQU 0 ECHO There are no saves. & GOTO :end
IF %test% GTR 0 ECHO There are saves. 
:END
PAUSE
```

An easier option would be.

```
FINDSTR /B "1: 2: 3: 4: 5:" Saves.txt >NUL 2>&1 && (ECHO There are saves.) || (ECHO There are no saves.)
```

If all your lines begin with a number and colon then you can just do this.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%G IN (saves.txt) do set numsaves=%%G
```

Comment: The answer works perfectly thank you. As for the suggestion, it wouldn't work since I still need that `test` counter to count how many instances are found.

Comment: I would suggest based on your 'check strings', that the better answer, _(An easier option would be.)_, should read `@FindStr "1: 2: 3: 4: 5:" Saves.txt >Nul && (Echo There are saves) || Echo There are no saves`. _You'll note here that `FindStr` doesn't output STDERR unless of course "1: 2: 3: 4: 5:" is not a valid entry, (which it is), or `Saves.txt` doesn't exist, (which it should), so there's no real need to redirect STDERR to NUL in this case._

Comment: @Pitdroid, could you provide an example of your saves.txt file.  We could probably come up with an even better solution if we could see the input.  Please update your question if you would like to.

Comment: Revising my code after looking at it again I didn't end up using the `%test%` variable. I used another for loop's counter. So your solution does work with the revised code as long as I add a colon after the numbers (every line starts with a number followed directly by a colon).

Comment: @Pitdroid, you should consider using the /B option to make sure that `FINDSTR` matches at the beginning of the line.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Pitdroid, instead of asking it would have been easier to enter `FindStr /?` at the Command Prompt and read the usage information! Examples: `FindStr "^[1-5]:" Saves.txt` or `FindStr /B "[1-5]:" Saves.txt`